# What are the pitfalls of using shared pointers everywhere?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Our codebase uses many vectors. And some of these vectors share objects with each other, i.e. they contain `std::shared_ptr` to shared objects. The problem is: the codebase is still on active development stage, and it's often needed to rewrite some vector containing values to a vector containing shared pointers. And this is tedious. So I came up with an idea: simply make ALL vectors as vectors of shared pointers.

The question: is it OK? Which caveats should I be aware of? What can go wrong?

I've made some simple and possibly naive measurements and there was practically no difference in terms of performance between a vector of values and a vector of shared pointers when initializing and querying them.

If performance is not the problem, is there anything else I should be aware of?

Comment: @Ron:vector of polymorphic types, of shared objects...

Comment: I provide counter examples (which seems to me not rare).

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get how polymorphism relates to the problem.

Comment: Polymorphism is one of the major reasons to use a pointer to an allocated object instead of just an object in modern C++.

Comment: I don't really get it. You say you have a bunch of vectors & that it takes time to refactor these into vectors of smart pointers. But you now want to do it to _all_ vectors. What does that gain you? Or were you thinking of changing how `std::vector` works?

Comment: If you have vectors with objects that you won't be sharing, then I would not suggest using a `shared_ptr` for them.  No need to pay for the bookkeeping `shared_ptr` does if you are not going to use it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's because the project is on early development stage. So, the majority of code is yet to be written.

Comment: @NathanOliver seems the only direct answer to my question, thanks!

Comment: @Shawn You are the 3rd person who said this, yet I don't understand why is that true. Can you please post some link to the explanation?

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev: `std::vector<Base>` cannot store `Derived`. There would be slicing.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev Then simply write the vectors the way you want them to be written... How can you have problems with code you haven't written yet? I don't get it.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev I already linked you to the explanation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit this is how I get the problems: 1) make a vector of values 2) write a lot of code that uses the vector 3) realize I need to share the values stored in the vector 4) rewrite 1 and 2 to vector of shared pointers

Comment: So you're asking whether, as a matter of development approach, you should create new vectors up-front to store pointers, just in case you late realise you need to have them store pointers? To that, I say: where is your planning? Why are you writing _even one line of code_ before you actually know what data you need and what components you need? Did you not make an architecture design up-front before starting to code? That's your real problem. Your suggestion is rather like wearing a massive raincoat everywhere you go, including onto a sunny beach, just because you did not look at the weather.

Comment: _(cont.)_ Instead, simply look at the weather.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well. I actually make A LOT of planning. I write docs, all the API, data structures up-front, etc. Yet, it's either me not smart enough or things are just complex, but things tend to change during development, because I always miss something when planning and that pops out later. I thought it's a commong thing and planning everything 100% correctly is a fantastic thing. Can you do this, I wonder? :-)

Comment: In my experience, using a `std::shared_ptr` has the same concerns that using global variables.  Sometimes it is the expedient thing to do, because the architecture is sideways in some ownership or relationship areas.  But I would use it as a last resort, not as your first choice and definitely not as prevalent throughout the code (even when there is no sharing of the `std::shared_ptr`, but the team just uses them out of habit, and because that how Java/JVM or C#/.NET do it).

Comment: If you know the entire API and all the data structures, then you know which vectors need shared pointers and which do not. Okay, sometimes things go wrong and plans have to adapt, but the sort of changes you're talking about are fundamental and indicate a process problem. You should fix that rather than taking your proposed approach.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Okay, thanks for sharing your view! It adds more confidence to my already made decision to assess the necessity of the pointers individually.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev Good :P

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a bad idea, JAVA does this, and often this causes problems when you loose track that the object is shared and you "broke" it with some temporary change somewhere in your huge codebase.

There is almost no performance issues with `std::vector` if you use it with objects inside, except if the contained objects are really big or with complex constructors.

You should use pointers (shared or not) in a vector only when strictly needed, for instance:

- if the contained object is polymorphic
- if the contained object has some non trivially cloneable field (IE `std::mutex`)
- if the contained object is really big (IE a video frame)

Comment: Can you please show or explain why polymorphic objects are important for the decision?

Comment: i read the question as vectors containing shared objects is the premise. You completely miss that point

Comment: The only caveat I see here is that sharing objects is bad because of side effects. But this is a requirement in our case. I am asking what *other* reasons to not do this exist.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev ^ That's the link about polymorphism. You should click on it.

Comment: Shared ownership of a mutex, what could possibly go wrong?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yep, thanks! I did exactly that right away :) But had postponed to read it (reading it now)